# Cant run composer require twig/extensions

Tags: symfony, terminal, composer-php, twig, twig-extension

So I am trinyg to install twig extensions to use truncate() twig filter, and cannot do it for some dependencies incompatabilities
When I run `composer require twig/extensions` I get this message :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - twig/extensions[v1.5.2, ..., 1.x-dev] require twig/twig ^1.27|^2.0 -> found twig/twig[v1.27.0, ..., 1.x-dev, v2.0.0, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v3.2.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version doe
s not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - twig/extensions[v1.5.0, ..., v1.5.1] require twig/twig ~1.27|~2.0 -> found twig/twig[v1.27.0, ..., 1.x-dev, v2.0.0, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v3.2.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does
 not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires twig/extensions ^1.5 -> satisfiable by twig/extensions[v1.5.0, ..., 1.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

It suggest me to run it with -W option, when I run it `composer require twig/extensions -W`

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1

    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.4 (conflict analysis result)

    - symfony/http-kernel v5.2.2 conflicts with twig/twig v2.12.0.

    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle v5.6.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v5.2.2].
    - twig/extra-bundle is locked to version v3.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle is locked to version v5.6.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - Root composer.json requires twig/extensions ^1.5 -> satisfiable by twig/extensions[v1.5.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - twig/extensions 1.x-dev requires twig/twig ^1.27|^2.0 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.12.0, ..., 2.x-dev].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: twig/twig[v2.12.0, ..., 2.x-dev, v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.x-dev].
    - twig/extra-bundle v3.2.1 requires twig/twig ^3.2 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v3.2.1, 3.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v3.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
```

This is my `composer.json` files require and require-dev

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.8",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.6",
        "symfony/asset": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.8",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.26",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.2.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: From the github [twig extension repo](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions). "WARNING: This repository is abandoned in favor of Twig Core Extra extensions." and "TextExtension: truncate, wordwrap filters: use the Twig string extra extension: u filter". The core extra bundle is installed by default under Symfony 5.2.

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** do you want to achieve by installing that deprecated package? If you don't want to look for alternatives, why not downgrade Twig to v2?